# Google Sheets' replacement for Excel's =DATEDIF()?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I imported my Excel spreadsheet to Google and have just one error in the formula that I cannot figure out.  I'm looking to calculate an anniversary date/years of service from the start date (D2) and of course today's date, using:

```
=DATEDIF(D2,TODAY(),"y")&" years "&DATEDIF(D2,TODAY(),"ym")&" months"
```

Google is giving me the error "unknown function name DATEDIF".

Does anyone know how to make this work in Google Docs?

Answer (score 4):

`datedif` is undocumented even in Excel,, just use plain formula in both applications:

```
=TODAY()-D2
```

in Excel you can use custom number format: `yy" years "mm" months"`, to get the right format in Google Docs use this formula:

```
=text(today()-D2, "yy' years 'mm' months'")
```

P.S.: excel equivalent of this formula is `=TEXT(TODAY()-D2, "yy"" years ""mm"" months""")`

Comment: Appreciate the helpful solution of just using date math.  What do you mean undocumented?  DATEDIF() is listed on the Google spreadsheet functions list right here https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?rd=2

Comment: @garec, that's hardly `Excel` documetnation. they might have added it to Google Docs since 2012 I guess.. maybe even to Excel 2013 docs, who knows..

Comment: It is in googledocs documentation but it doesnt seem to work https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612 Maybe it works with their new Google sheets but I'm using an old file

Answer (score 2):

If you still use the old Google Docs like I do, you can use these formulas instead as equivalent

```
DDd =DATEDIF($A2;$B2;"d") =INT($B2-$A2)
DDm =DATEDIF($A2;$B2;"m") =12*(YEAR($B2)-YEAR($A2))+MONTH($B2)-MONTH($A2)-(DAY($B2)<DAY($A2))
DDy =DATEDIF($A2;$B2;"y") =YEAR($B2)-YEAR($A2)-IF(MONTH($A2)>MONTH($B2);1;IF(MONTH($A2)=MONTH($B2);DAY($A2)>DAY($B2);0))
```

Source https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=8791#p42479